# QNetworkRequest for Twitter OAuth2 Returns Forbidden Error

Tags: c++, qt, twitter, oauth, qnetworkaccessmanager

I've been trying to make the Application-only authentication of Twitter API work on Qt. When I run my code, I get this error:

```
Failure "Error transferring https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token - server replied: Forbidden"
```

Here's my request code:

```
    QJsonObject params;
    params.insert("grant_type","client_credentials");

    QUrl url("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    QString authorizationKey =  m_consumerKey + ":" + m_consumerSecret;
    QByteArray encryptedAuth = authorizationKey.toUtf8().toBase64();
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "My App v1.0.0");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ encryptedAuth);
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setSslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());

    QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkManager->post(request, QJsonDocument(params).toJson());
```

Maybe I'm missing out something?

Comment: Did this work previously? I ask because Twitter's API documentation specifically states that "Tokens received by this method should be cached. If attempted too frequently, requests will be rejected with a HTTP 403 with code 99."

Comment: It actually never worked. From the start, I always got this error. When I tried requesting using XMLHttpRequest in javascript, i received a token. But I want it to work on C++ :(

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue. It turned out, I was sending a wrong format for the body of the request. I changed:

```
QJsonObject params;
params.insert("grant_type","client_credentials");
...
QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkManager->post(request, QJsonDocument(params).toJson());
```

to:

```
QUrlQuery payload;
payload.addQueryItem("grant_type","client_credentials");
QByteArray postData = payload.query(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8();
...
QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkManager->post(request, postData);
```